# Fish shell ESC/META keybinding with iterm2 on os x yosemite

Tags: key-bindings, fish, iterm2

How can I use emacs style forward/back word jumping in fish using ESC/META? In the fish shell, I tried the following w/ no effect.

```
bind \eb prevd-or-backward-word
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the correct key binding, and you'll see it work if you press escape and b fast enough together.

You probably want to use your option key as Escape. To make that work, set Option key to "+Esc" in the Keys tab of your iTerm2 profile. See the "How do I make the option/alt key act like Meta or send escape codes?" question of the [iTerm2 FAQ](https://iterm2.com/faq.html) for more detailed instructions.